# how to end this ' cast' and 'case' statement?

Tags: mysql, case

```
 with t1 as
     (select Name,Sex,Team,Games,City,sport,event,medal,CAST(case when age='NA' then '0' else age end as varchar(20)) as age
      from athlete_events ),
     t2 as
     (select * from t1 where Medal in('Gold','Silver'))
     select * from t2 where Age>=60
```

**` How do I end this case statement. in CAST(case when age='NA' then '0' else age end as varchar(20)) as age
from athlete_events ) ? as I am getting wrong 'varchar is not valid at this position!!**

Answer (score 0):

It isn't clear what the actual type of the `Age` column is, but the `WHERE` clause appears that it is numeric.  Assuming this, and also assuming that missing values are `NULL`, you should just be using `COALESCE()` here:

```sql
SELECT Name, Sex, Team, Games, City, sport, event, medal, COALESCE(Age, 0) AS Age
FROM athlete_events
WHERE Medal IN ('Gold', 'Silver') AND
      COALESCE(Age, 0) > 0;
```

Note: The CTEs you are using also seem largely unnecessary.